# Core Data relationship not nil but returns nil object

Tags: ios, xcode, core-data, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I have entity:

```
@class CDCustomItem;

@interface CDCustomItem : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) CDCustomImage *image;
@end
```

and `CDCustomImage` entity:

```
@class CDCustomImage;

@interface CDCustomImage : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * url;
@property (nonatomic, retain) CDCustomItem *itemParent;

@end
```

CDCustomImage.image and CDCustomImage.itemParent have types "To One"

After I insert image to CDCustomItem it shows me in `NSLog`:

```
image = "0x79e59df0 <x-coredata:///CDCustomImage/t765B46F3-87B1-4C09-A108-6584F4E58DDB214>";
```

But when I'm trying to `NSLog(@"%@", CDCustomItem.image)` it returns `null`

Why its happened? How to fix it? Please help

**Edit 1:**
All operations are in one thread

**Edit 2:**
Here is code how inserting image to CDCustomItem:

```
CDCustomImage *image = [self insertImage:[jsonDict objectForKey:@"image"]];
item.image = image;

- (CDCustomImage *)insertImage:(NSDictionary *)jsonDict {
    CDCustomImage *entity = [self insertEntityWithName:[CDCustomImage description]];
    [self fillFieldsForImage:entity dict:jsonDict];

    return entity;
}

- (void)fillFieldsForImage:(CDCustomImage *)entity dict:(NSDictionary *)jsonDict {
    entity.url = [jsonDict valueForKey:@"url"];
}
```

Comment: Do you have, by any chance, an accentuated character in your image url ?

Comment: Please can you show the code to insert the image to the CDCustomItem?

Comment: pbasdf, yes, have added sample code..

Comment: At what points were you using `NSLog`?  Is `item` non-nil when you set `item.image = image`?  Is there any error when you save your context?

Comment: I found error, item was setting twice into contextobject (first time with image, second without)..